# How to reformulate ${\left\| {Ax + b} \right\|^2} \le c + {b^T}b - r$ as an SOCP constraint?

Tags: optimization, second-order-cone-programming

I am running into a constrain that looks quite similar but not really in the standard form of an SOCP. That is:

$${\left\| {Ax + b} \right\|^2} \le c + {b^T}b - r$$

Standard form of SOCP:

$$\left\| {Ax + b} \right\| \le {c^T}x + d$$

Is it possible to reformulate this constraint as SOCP ? And if so how can I do it ?

Comment: You just need to take the square root.

Comment: The suggestion of @MarcDinh is the easiest but only works when $c$, $b$ and $r$ are all parameters. I'll add an answer for the general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the typical reformulation when the right hand side of your constraint is not a parameter:
$$\left\lVert \begin{pmatrix}2(Ax+b) \\ c+b^Tb-r - 1 \end{pmatrix} \right\rVert \leq c+b^Tb-r + 1$$

Comment: THank you, is this the reformulation base on the hyperbolic constraint reformulation ${w^2} \le xy$ where $w$ is $Ax + b$ with $x$ is $ c + {b^T}b - r$  and $y=1$?

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh yes, that's the one